# Is it possible to write in a newly added column

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to extend my spreadsheet with a new column for every row and write in the newly added column some information. Is it possible?

edit: I have a spreadsheet with 2 columns, the second is like a user-id. Now I made a script which creates a new HTTP request with the given user-id, and the return is json structure. I would like to populate the rows with additional data from this json. For this I need to add new columns, iterate over them and write data in them.

Starting from the tutorial, I have made:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  sheet.insertColumnAfter(2);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    getData(data[i][1]);
  }
}

function getData(user) {
  var url = "https://api.lootbox.eu/pc/eu/" + user + "/profile";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json"
    }
  });
  Logger.log(response);
  // write the data in the newly added column
}
```

Comment: yes, it is possible? can you explain more?

Comment: @NitinDhomse I have a spreadsheet with 2 columns, the second is like a user-id. Now I made a script which creates a new HTTP request with the given user-id, and the return is json structure. I would like to populate the rows with additional data from this json. For this I need to add new columns, iterate over them and write data in them.

Answer (score 0):

Inserts a number of columns after the given column position.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 // This inserts a column in the second column position
 sheet.insertColumnsAfter(1);
```

Comment: It's not the insert but writing to the new column which is the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the index of the column after creation:

```js
var cellToWrite = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, columnIndex, 1, 1);
cellToWrite.setValue(yourValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
var COL = 2;

function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  sheet.insertColumnAfter(COL);
  // data of the new column
  var dataNewCol = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var response = getData(data[i][1]);
    dataNewCol[i] = [];
    dataNewCol[i][0] = response;
  }
  // Set Values in the newly added column (COL+1)
  sheet.getRange(1,COL+1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).setValues(dataNewCol);
}

function getData(user) {
  var url = "https://api.lootbox.eu/pc/eu/" + user + "/profile";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json"
    }
  });
  Logger.log(response);
  // return data
  return response;
}
```